# How Do I recover Uninstalled module in ORchardCMS

Tags: orchardcms-1.9

I'm developing website using Orchard CMS and I just unintentionally uninstalled a module in orchard cms. Now I need to recover it. Please let me know how can I recover an uninstalled module in orchard cms?
I can see under appData folder that module is stored as moduleName.delted but it seems useless. 
I'm in a fix as I spent a lot of time in developing that module and due to similarity in names just uninstalled wrong moduel..
Module is an empty folder now.

I would appreciate your response.
Thanks,
Sohaib